Android 14 .Net8 Maui Blazor Keyboard not showing
I have upgraded a Maui Blazor Android app from .Net7 to .Net8 to support the latest API Level.
After Upgrading, the app now does not seem to bring up the keyboard when pressing any of the InputText entries. The log shows the following:
[IMM_LC] ssi() - flag : 0 view : com.companyname.appname reason = SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
[IMM_LC] ssi() view is not EditText
[IMM_LC] ssi() - cancel : servedView != view, servedView=DecorView@87f8a2e[MainActivity],focus=false,windowFocus=true,autofillUiShowing=false,window=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@bfccff0,displayId=0,temporaryDetach=false,hasImeFocus=true, view=crc64d693e2d9159537db.BlazorAndroidWebView{86ce70d VF.DHVC.. ........ 0,0-1080,2205},focus=false,windowFocus=true,autofillUiShowing=false,window=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@bfccff0,displayId=0,temporaryDetach=false,hasImeFocus=true
I believe that the root cause of this will be due to it not being in focus, however I am confused at:
A) The actual reasoning for this. Why has a fairly standard upgrade gone so awry?
B) Has this issue been experienced by any other users? I have searched and can only find examples from Android 12 Java, and don't really seem to have the same issue.
C) Any ideas on a solution for a system wide fix? If not, just a fix will suffice.
If you need any info from me, please let me know.

Did the keyboard show on the other android versions?

First of all, I created a new .Net8 Maui Blazor project with the defaul template. And the keyboard can show successfully when I click the <input> in the razor page:
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
Welcome to your new app.
<input />

So you can copy your code into a new .Net8 Maui Blazor and then test again.
In addition, you can refer to the wiki about Upgrading .NET MAUI from .NET 7 to .NET 8 to check if you have any mistake when upgraging or not.
Finally, you said:

I believe that the root cause of this will be due to it not being in focus

You can use the following code to make the webview and child view can be focused. Override the page's OnHandlerChanged() Method:
        protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
        {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
            var androidweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
            //blazorWebView is the x:Name of the BlazorWebView in the xaml
            androidweb.Focusable = true;
            //make the webview can be focused
            androidweb.RequestFocus(Android.Views.FocusSearchDirection.Down);
            //request focus when clicked
#endif
        }

